# Fortran OverWrite

Tags: fortran, overwrite

I'm trying to write a fortran code that reads name, surname and number and then writes them into already existing file.

Here is what the code looks like: http://pastebin.com/SV8erDND

Now, there'are only 2 lines in the "Deneme.txt" file, which look like this;

```
john mayer 110
hugh jackman 111
```

whenever i try to add another name to the file by the compiler, it overwrites the second line. For example, if I type dennis lui 510, the file now looks like this;

```
john mayer 110
dennis lui 510
```

How do I prevent it from overwriting? Also, there doesn't seem to be loop. After adding the first name/surname/number, I want it to go back to first step and ask for another name/surname/number.

Answer (score 2):

First you read a line from the file, then you're asking the user to enter a name. If it matches the one name you just read, the program asks for another name. If it is a new name, it will start writing where the last read stopped, that is on the second line.

Your check if a name already exists doesn't make much sense, since you only check against the first name. What should be done is to read the whole file, store the data in a hash table and then append at the end any name/number entered by the user that is not found in the hash. Are you trying to implement some kind of database? If so, then I don't think Fortran is the best option to arrive at a easy/quick solution, maybe you should go for a language like perl or python.

Comment: Isn't it other way around? If the names matches, it should say "it already exists" and if it doesn't, then i want it to add to the third line, fourth line etc.

Well, I'm learning Fortran this semester and merely wanted to see if I can do something like that. 

"Ask for the name"
"Ask for the surname"
If they are already in the file, it should ask the user to retype again. If not,
"Ask for the number"
Then add the information in order(2nd line, 3rd line, 4th line, 5th line)

Comment: It is not unusual for different people to have the same name.